# Visual Studio 2008 Cut and Paste Won't Overwrite

Tags: visual-studio

When I paste over selected text, the contents of the clipboard are appended to the existing text instead of overwriting it. I can't seem to find the setting to change this behavior!

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Tools -> Options -> Keyboard (under Environment) is your mapping scheme set to emacs?

If it is, see [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=365222).

Comment: Mapping is not set to emacs but the description from the link describes the problem perfectly.

Comment: Resetting the keyboard mapping scheme to default worked. This was driving me nuts. Thanks!

Comment: I spoke to soon. Resetting the keyboard mapping scheme to default did not work. I can overwrite selected text in Source view but pasting text to selected text just appends it. Nuts!